# What's the name of my sound card driver's file?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to run fuser to determine what process is using my sound card, but I don't know what file to use. I ran fuser on /System/Library/Extensions while playing a YouTube video, but did not see any process IDs.

Comment: i'm really not sure it works like that on Mac - [Mac fuser man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fuser.1.html) it's likely to all go through CoreAudio

Comment: What kind of MacBook is it?  What version of the operating system is it running? Is the sound card the one supplied with the computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea of which process is making the sound, you might be able to try them until you find it.  For example, QuickTime Player, when playing a movie, does not use any subprocesses.  Similarly iTunes when it is playing a song.

On OS X 10.7 Lion, I did the following:

- open Activity Monitor,
- switch to "All Processes, Hierarchically"
- found the application process I wanted and clicked it,
- clicked Inspect
- clicked Open Files and Ports